# Trace of a function from $W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ is zero?

Tags: measure-theory, sobolev-spaces

Assume that $u \in W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^N)$, where $p>1$ and $N \geq 2$. 
We know only that $u \equiv 0$ in an open ball $B \subset \mathbb{R}^N$. 
Is it true that the trace of $u$ equals zero on the boundary of $B$? In other words, is it true that
$$
Tu = 0 \quad \text{on} \quad \partial B \,?
$$

Intuitively, the answer seems to be affirmative, but I'm afraid that $u$ could have some "jumps" on $\partial B$ which prevent $Tu=0$.

As an approach, we definitely know that $Tu = 0$ on each sphere $\partial B_1$ compactly contained inside $B$. Then we can expand $B_1$ and look what happens with $Tu$. So, my initial question can be reformulated as follows: 
Is the trace operator continuous with respect to a smooth change of (smooth) boundary of a subdomain of $\mathbb{R}^N$?

Comment: Yes, the trace is zero. Depending on your definition of "trace", it could be proved by approximation with smooth functions or by capacity theory. I do not know the answer to your question concerning the continuity w.r.t. the change of the boundary.

Comment: @gerw Under the "trace" I mean a bounded linear operator which maps $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ to $L^p(\partial \Omega)$. Could you expand your suggestion about the proof, please?

Comment: You can use a standard procedure (smooth cut-off + mollifying) to approximate $u$ by a functions $\varphi \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ which are zero on balls slightly larger than $B$. These functions have zero trace.

Comment: @gerw I know that we can approximate $u$ by convolution with mollifiers, and such approximative functions will be zero on balls slightly *smaller* than $B$. Also I know that if we multiply mollifiers by cut-off, then it works to show that $C_0^\infty(\Omega)$ is dense in $L^p(\Omega)$. However, the last result is not true in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$. Could you clarify your arguments, please?

Comment: But it is dense in $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$ and $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega) = W^{1,p}(\Omega)$. In principle, you can transfer the arguments of https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC300210/

Comment: @gerw We definitely have $W_0^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^N) = W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^N)$. However, in my initial question the behaviour of $u$ at infinity is not important at al, and it is enough to consider $\Omega$ be a bounded domain. In this case, $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega) \not\equiv W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ and it is still not clear for me how to approximate $u$ by $C_0^\infty(\Omega)$.

Comment: In the proof of Meyers&Serring, they do such approximation by $C_0^\infty(\Omega)$ only *localy*, i.e. they show, in principal, that there exist $u_k \in C_0^\infty(\Omega)$ such that $u_k \to u$ in $W^{1,p}_{loc}(\Omega)$. Globally, they can approximate $u$ by $C^\infty(\Omega)$ only (no compact support, in general). And it is not clear for me how to use this idea for my aims. How do you think?